# Deployed docker image is not converting date to Spanish

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

I have the following code that correctly converts the month name to Spanish while debugging in Visual Studio. However, when I deploy this code, including an image, within a Docker container, it fails to convert the month name to Spanish, and it remains in English. Here is the code:

```
var ci = new CultureInfo("es");
var dateStr = DateTime.Now;
var result = dateStr.ToString("M", ci);
```

I'm looking for a solution to ensure that the month name is displayed in Spanish even after deploying the Docker image. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the base image you are using, you may need to install ICU if it is not present. You can find additional details here: https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/samples/enable-globalization.md